# What are the differences between self-deleting a post, and having a moderator delete it by owner request?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694391/how-to-print-the-object-value-of-xml-file-in-string-formatfirst-in-the-log-cat) which I have posted for which I am the owner of this question. I want to get it deleted (there's no answer for it, nor down votes) and the question is useless. For which I have two options of deleting

1. Delete it myself
2. Request a moderator to delete it

I don't get what the differences are between them:

- Are there any effects on reputation?
- Does it count toward a question ban if I delete it, but not if a moderator deletes it?
- What is the visibility of the question to other users?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the first place you should delete it yourself - there's no need to involve a moderator in this - as there are no upvoted answers.

As far as the effect of the deletion is concerned:

1. If it's deleted by a moderator you won't be able to undelete it yourself (you'd need to flag for moderator again), should you change your mind.
2. There's no difference in the effect it has on a question ban. It will count against you regardless of whether it was deleted by a moderator or by yourself.
3. In both cases the question will be visible to yourself and 10k users - **if you have the link**. The only people who can find the question by searching or through your profile are those with diamond moderator abilities.