# Seeking ways to improve previous posts

Tags: discussion, post-ban

## What this post is NOT

1. **Not** a post asking to get unbanned.
2. **Not** a post begging for upvotes.
3. **Not** a flame post.

## Related

https://stackoverflow.com/help
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans
[What are the differences between self-deleting a post, and having a moderator delete it by owner request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267447/what-are-the-differences-between-self-deleting-a-post-and-having-a-moderator-de)

---

Now that this is out of the way;

*On Stack Overflow*

Today, I received this nice message regarding my past low-quality questions:

> [image: Warning message]

I have noticed that most of my questions could fall in the category of flag `off-topic->Simple Typographic error`. When I originally asked my questions, I had searched on answers or ways to solve them. I never thought they would actually just be a small tiny mistake. Because of that, most of my questions are *0* or *-1* scored.

I have two questions :

1. What do I do with these questions? (Or : **What can someone do, stuck in a similar position to mine?**)

   - Do I delete them? No, I would get banned because each deleted questions counts towards the ban.
   - Do I edit them? I can't really improve them more..
   - Else?
2. I would like to have **constructive** criticism on my questions on what I could improve (I'd like to improve myself). It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Simple Typographic Error" questions are pretty much useless to other users. If a moderator deletes them, would it count against the OP? Not, equally, or less than when Sifu deletes them?

Comment: @Jongware See this meta to answer your question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267447/what-are-the-differences-between-self-deleting-a-post-and-having-a-moderator-de

Comment: @Kendra: ouch. So no realistic options there for the OP -- I don't believe one could improve such questions without a total rewrite.

Comment: @Jongware But doing a total rewrite would make the answers obsolete..

Comment: @Jongware I don't either- But I don't feel I have enough experience with the site to say for sure. Best I can do is point to a relevant meta.

Comment: @Sifu, yes sorry, I meant to add that. A "Total Rewrite" is frowned upon in general.

Comment: because you've asked a lot of questions containing simple typographical errors, perhaps you should increase your skill at recognizing these types of errors, or use an IDE to help you. most users do not have this happen so frequently, so it sounds like the problem lies in your habits. go through your code a few times before asking a question to make sure there aren't any such errors.

Comment: @Sgroved, it is not so much about something I missed, but more about little rules that I didn't know that aren't obvious. For example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140143/ie8-float-problems-arise-again , I didn't know that IE8 was case sensitive for its style sheets, how could I know? This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765128/ie8-style-inline-block reflects how much I searched before posting the question, again it wasn't easy to find. Please don't say that I haven't searched enough before posting a question, I usually take hours before posting a question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"Simple Typographic Error" questions are typically a lost cause. There's not much you can do to make them useful, so I wouldn't draw attention (and downvotes) to them by editing.

[How to prevent a user from resubmitting a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25040281/1288) could have been better if you'd included the code you were using, but it's not really a bad question. You might be able to get an upvote or two if you include the code you had started with.

You don't need to use "EDIT" or "UPDATE" to punctuate questions like you do in [IE8 won't display PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24658163/1288). The question would be improved by removing the multiple "UPDATE" headings you added. [Styling working on Firefox AND IE8 but NOT on Chrome (Centered vs text-align=left)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24531305/1288) has the same problem near the end. When you make an edit, aim to have it read like part of the original post.

The rest of your questions look good, so you should also concentrate on putting distance between yourself and a question ban by asking really good new questions and by posting more answers.

Comment: Very appreciated, I'll edit my questions accordingly and will keep in mind what you said for my future edits/questions.