# Seeking ways to improve a previous question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality-improvement

This is

- **not** a post asking for unbanned;
- **not** a post complaining about downvotes;
- **not** a post begging for upvotes.

This is not a duplicate of [Seeking ways to improve previous posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267783/758077), although it is phrased in a similar way.

I have received the following message from SO regarding my past badly-received questions:

> [image]

Having read the [how-to-ask instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I would like to improve my past questions (if it can be done) one by one until I don't see the warning message before asking any new one. Specifically in this post, I am working on the following one:

[How to read a text file containing "null" into an Integer array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48042801/758077)

> Here are my questions:
>
> What do I do with the linked question above? (Or : **What can someone do, stuck in a similar position to mine?**)
>
> - Do I delete them? No, I would get banned because each deleted questions counts towards the ban. Moreover, the post has had an accepted answer.
> - Do I edit them? I can't really improve them more to the best of my knowledge. (One rule in the [how-to-ask instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I am currently violating is "Introduce the problem before you post any code". But my question is essentially based on the code. I don't know how to rewrite it to fit the rule.)
> - Do I wait for the community deleting the question?
> - Else?

I would like to have **constructive** criticism on the linked question on what I could improve.

Comment: I'm not sure that your linked-to question *can* be improved, or improved much. Best would be if you showed your own attempt to solve this, *at that time* and used that information to make your question much more specific. Else it looks mostly like a work request type of question (how do I do such-and-such where I don't show an attempt), a multi-step question (questions should only be singular -- ask about one step), and a duplicate of several previous questions, including how to read from a text file, how to parse ints, how to respond to int parsing exceptions...

Comment: Best to use that question and its problems to help guide you not to ask similar questions in the future.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: thanks for your comments! I was thinking that there is not much can be done for that particular question other than deleting it. But then I seem to fall into a dilemma: I can neither improve it or delete it.